# How to turn on security (Winsock Secure Socket Extensions) for sockets in .net

Tags: c#, sockets, security

We are currently working on a simple UDP relay server, which forwards UDP packages from one client to all other clients connected to the same port.

For XBOX One we need to implement [Secure Sockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/winsock-secure-socket-extensions). Unfortunatelly this extension is only available in C++, but our server code is a .net application written in C#.

To make a socket secure in C++ we would simply call:

```
// Turn on security for the socket.
sockErr = WSASetSocketSecurity(sock, securitySettings, settingsLen, NULL, NULL);
```

But I have no idea how to do this in C#. I could not find any equivalent for *WSASetSocketSecurity* in .net. Is this not supported?

Comment: You can use the Windows dll ws2_32 with DLLImport.  See www.pinvoke.net.

Comment: Thx you @jdweng for your fast answer. The _WSASetSocketSecurity_ function seems to be part of _Fwpuclnt.dll_. Unfortunatelly www.pinvoke.net does not contain any code examples for that library. I am a total C++ noob. Could you be so kind and help me with finding the right translation for the parameters.

`SOCKET WSAAPI WSASocketA(int af, int type, int protocol, LPWSAPROTOCOL_INFOA lpProtocolInfo, GROUP g, DWORD dwFlags);`
Should translate into something like that:
`public static extern Int32 WSASetSocketSecurity(IntPtr socket, ..? );`
Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: See following : https://www.elitepvpers.com/forum/co2-programming/159327-advanced-winsock-c.html